# How to enable both eth0 and wwan0 in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

My Scenario is: - eth0(Ethernet) port for device communication
- wwan0(GSM) for my internet connectivity

How do i enable both in ubuntu , i have tried few ways but always anyone is getting enabled . Is there any way to do it? Please suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

In the file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:0C:29:90:24:0F,00:0C:29:2E:C8:2C,

[ifupdown]
managed=false  ---> true

where false means that network-manager doesn't manage the interfaces located in the file /etc/network/interfaces.

And added the below in /etc/rc.local file,

ifconfig wwano up
ifconfig eth0 up